# Moving in-game menus in a loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have several in-game menus that open up when I press the Tab key (Items, Map, Lore etc..) and I want to make them move in a loop when the user is pressing the right/left buttons I've added.

For example:
If the order is *Items|Map|Lore*, and the player is looking at the Map menu, if they press right they reach *Lore*, and if they press right **again** they reach *Items* (rather than the current nothingness).

This is my left button code (same goes for right button of course but with -2560f for the x value):

```
public void LeftUIButton()
    {
        var moveMenusRight = new Vector3(2560f, 0, 0);
        foreach(GameObject canvas in uICanvases.Keys)
        {
            Vector3 targetPosition = canvas.transform.position + canvas.transform.TransformVector(moveMenusRight);
            StartCoroutine(LerpCanvas(canvas, targetPosition, uICanvasesSlidingTime));
        }
    }
```

The *uICanvases* is a dictionary I'm filling up in my *Awake* test method:

```
private Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3> uICanvases = new Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameOverScreen.SetActive(false);
        
        // Adds all the GameObjects that are tagged as "UICanvas" to a list to be worked on.
        foreach(GameObject canvas in FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
        {
            if (canvas.CompareTag("UICanvas"))
            {
                uICanvases.Add(canvas, canvas.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also want to keep the code as generic as possible, without committing to anything hard-coded.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In general I would go with a) have only 3 panels b) in the center one you always display the currently active panel c) when you go left and right you spawn the according next panel and move to it d) once reached you again snap back to the center panel and replace the content by the now new active panel .. the left and right panel can even only be spawned add-hoc when moving and be removed otherwise.. this way you can have a wrap around loop but without actually having all items on all the time

Comment: @derHugo What you're describing is limiting the abilities of the code and its versatility. I don't want to have only 3 panels, I want to have an unlimited amount. I can spawn the objects on the right/left (depending on button pressed) and then slide them to the middle, but for that I'll need to create a different structure all together and have to take into consideration the order of the objects - something I want to avoid.
I want the user to be able to simply add panels and it will work automatically like now, only also loop.
If I can't figure that out I'll resort to the other option...

Comment: Dude .. what I described is not limiting the amount of panels in total ... it is rather suggesting a trick so you don't need to have the exact amount of panels always enabled .. you just need exactly 2 panels: the current one and the one you are moving to. Once reached you snap back and replace the panel by the new current one .. that's it .. infinite amount of panels and wrap around is totally possible with that

Comment: I think I didn't understood you earlier then.
You mean to have 3 on at the same time, like X->Y<-Z, and when I am on Y (middle one, the one seen on screen) and move right I will spawn Z's right wing (if none exist then it will be the leftmost one, in this case X), move Y to the left, Z to the left (now is in middle) and now I have Y->Z<-X.

So in order to do that I just need in my Awake() method (where I fetch all the canvases) to define for each one what are its neighbors.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah kind of .. your so far used panels would rather be prefabs in a list. You only have active at the idle state `Y`. Now when you user moves e.g. right, you spawn the next panel (next index in the prefab list) so you have `Y - Z`. Now you move them to the left (user apparently scrolls right). Then once reached `Z` you destroy `Y` and `Z` is now your new center/active panel. How many of those panels are on at the same time depends on whether you only want to see the current and moving panel or also like a sneak to the left and right